# Receive toast messages without Accessibility?

Tags: android, android-toast

I have an app that reads notifications through TTS. With Google's change in policy for apps using Accessibility, I switched to Notification Listener, though that meant I had to remove the option to read toast messages. I released the update last night and already received feedback from someone who wanted the toast feature back.

Is there any way to read toast messages without using Accessibility? My search for a solution came up empty.

**Update (2018-01-16)**

After a little digging into the Android source, I found this relevant method in the Toast class (API 27):

```
private void trySendAccessibilityEvent() {
    AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager =
            AccessibilityManager.getInstance(mView.getContext());
    if (!accessibilityManager.isEnabled()) {
        return;
    }
    // treat toasts as notifications since they are used to
    // announce a transient piece of information to the user
    AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED);
    event.setClassName(getClass().getName());
    event.setPackageName(mView.getContext().getPackageName());
    mView.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
    accessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event);
}
```

That makes it clear that if no accessibility services are enabled, toasts aren't dispatched to the handler that AccessibilityService uses, so some kind of hack to access toasts the same way Accessibility gets them would be impossible without any services enabled. Of course, I'm trying to avoid creating an accessibility service again and don't want to rely on users having a different one enabled.

It appears that if there is any way to access toasts without Accessibility, it may have to be some fairly complex reflection to reach `Toast$TN.mNextView` or `.mView` through `com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.mToastQueue` and `$ToastRecord.callback`. It's a bit over my head right now as I'm not very familiar with reflection, but I'm still digging.